# C++ 20 concept to accept a random access container but reject std::list

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

`std::vector` is known to meet the requirement of a `RandomAccessContainer`, so using the `[]` operator is constant time. However, `std::list` only meets the weaker requirements of a `Container` and `ReversibleContainer`, and hence retrieving an element is O(N), moreover the `[]` operator doesn't exist.

I would like to constrain a template so that I can get a nice compile-time error whenever the `[]` operator doesn't exist or is not O(1). How can I achieve this?

Currently, on g++ 11.2.0, I cannot get a clean error message when instantiating the following templates with a `std::list`:

```cpp
template<typename RandomAccessContainer>
void foo(RandomAccessContainer const & x);
```

```cpp
template<typename ContiguousContainer>
void foo(ContiguousContainer const & x);
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
requires ContiguousContainer<T>
void foo(T const & x);
```

Comment: What’s your definition of `ContiguousContainer`?

Comment: ContiguousContainer is defined by the standard library; I was simply trying to find a syntax that works.

Comment: It’s defined, yes, but not as a C++ entity (despite appearing as an identifier in standard library synopses).  It’s a notation describing requirements on a program that is formally unrelated to the C++20 concepts (the language facility or the ones in the standard library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with a type trait to check if the type supports subscripting:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct has_subscript {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template<class U>
    static auto test(const U& t) -> decltype(t[0], std::true_type{});

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool has_subscript_v = has_subscript<T>::value;
```

Then add concepts:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept subscriptable = has_subscript_v<T>;

template <class T>
concept subscript_and_cont_iterator =
    std::contiguous_iterator<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()))> &&
    subscriptable<T>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vodeaT58G)

If you don't need the type trait, just make `subscriptable` using a `requires` clause:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept subscriptable = requires(const T& c) { c[0]; };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pbvnzrahe)

Comment: Great answer; very surprised this concept is not part of std, but I guess C++20 was pretty ambitious.

Comment: @user14717 Thanks! Yes, I have hardly worked with concepts at all yet. It seems to make a lot of things easier though. :)

Comment: traits could use `std::iterator_traits::iterator_category` (or even [`iterator_concept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags#Iterator_concept))

Comment: @Jarod42 Do you mean that any of those could be used in the `has_subscript` trait?

Comment: Not `has_subscript`, but `RandomAccessContainer` might be defined as a container with `iterator` with `random_access_iterator_tag` category.

Comment: @Jarod42 Aha, yes, that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

The Ranges library comes with a bunch of range-related concepts. In this case, you want:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::random_access_range R>
void foo(R&& x);
```

This concept doesn't check if the range itself has `[]` (and that's insufficient for you anyway, `map` provides that but isn't random access), but it does check that the iterator is a random access iterator, and random access iterators are required to themselves support indexing.

So rather than `x[2]` you have to write `ranges::begin(x)[2]`.